# I install SSL but still getting some http content on my site

Tags: ssl, magento-1.9.3.4

I install ssl and enable , i also change `use secure url:yes` for `frontend` and `backend` as well. but when I change `base_url` then site can not load error occur. my magento store on cloudfare. i cleared a cache also, but getting same result. can any one help me?

```
magento version:1.9.3.4.
```

[image]

If i put below `code` in `.htaccess` than magento give `500 Internal Server Error`
`.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fashionwithdeals.com/ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Afer Select "Full SSL" on cloud fare , getting below error :
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: site not loading , too many redirection

Comment: i upload my error pic

Comment: if i put `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fashionwithdeals.com/ $1 [L,R=301]` in .htaccess than give 500 internal server error

Comment: are you using ssl of your site or cloudfare ssl?

Comment: cloudfare ssl used

Comment: hello sunil , I update my question please review on this